# New mobile chat is sometimes missing most icons on meta site chats?

Tags: bug, chat, user-interface, mobile-web, icons

I couldn't find this bug elsewhere.

[image: missing icons circles in red, freehand]

When clicking on a message there should be more icons.

I've seen this multiple times, but I can't reproduce it now.

Comment: Oh that happened to me vaguely regularly on chat then suddenly stopped/ No idea why. And I appreciate the attempt to hide the battery life for those it would cause anxiety to, but the tank's only a little under a quarter full :D

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, idea stolen from [here](https://twitter.com/nathanwpyle/status/1480602661875556358) on twitter. Looks like I've been rumbled though!